# jquery issue with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a way to show and hide content inside of divs (based on class) when a user clicks on an anchor link with a specific ID.

I have an A-Z index of letters with anchor links. When someone clicks on a specific link (letter) javascript hides (fadeOut) ALL divs with the specific classes listed. Then the script displays (fadeIn) the div I am after.

Issue is there are 13 of these and I've shared the first 3 below to help give context.

What is happening is some weird timing and delay issues when clicking back and forth between letters. Sometimes the div displaying persists and doesn't fadeOut for a long time even though I have the timing set very short.

I'm sure there is a smarter way to go about this in perhaps a few functions, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Let me know if you have any questions, or need more detail and context.

```
$('#letter-a').mousedown(function(){    
    $('.letter-b, .letter-c, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $('.letter-a').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
    });
});

$('#letter-b').mousedown(function(){    
    $('.letter-a, .letter-c, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $('.letter-b').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
    });
});

$('#letter-c').mousedown(function(){    
    $('.letter-a, .letter-b, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $('.letter-c').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, if i got your question right, you want to make an accordion, which means : you want just to have one div visible in same time. Acutally is not very hard to do it, but i always use a plugin because i'm sure i have no errors. Try one of them http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.stop(true,true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

smaller version of your code

```
var cls_all = $('[class*="letter-"]'); //cached
$('[id^="letter-"]').mousedown(function () {
    var cls = this.id;
    cls_all.not('.' + cls).stop(true, true).fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.' + cls).delay(600).stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

---

[^ attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[* attribute-contains-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: @PSL i thought of doing the same but `this` refers to `id^="letter-` and OP want class .They are different i suppose .

Comment: Yeah i realized later.. Quick look had that thought... :) probably you can cache `$('[class*="letter-"]')` outside and use that as well.

Comment: My extreme thanks to you Tushar for this solution. What I had as 84 lines of code you have condensed into 7. Pure Genius—I am very grateful! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening is some weird timing and delay issues when clicking
>   back and forth between letters.

Try to use stop() method (http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$('.letter-b, .letter-c, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').stop().fadeOut(100, function(){
        $('.letter-a').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
    });
```

If it will not help - try to replace delay() with setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#letter-a').mousedown(function () {
    $('.letter-b, .letter-c, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.letter-a').fadeIn(500);, 600);
        });
    });

$('#letter-b').mousedown(function () {
    $('.letter-a, .letter-c, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.letter-b').fadeIn(500);, 600);
        });
    });

$('#letter-c').mousedown(function () {
    $('.letter-a, .letter-b, .letter-g, .letter-h, .letter-i, .letter-m, .letter-n, .letter-o, .letter-r, .letter-s, .letter-t, .letter-u, .letter-w').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.letter-c').fadeIn(500);, 600);
    });
});
```